# Smart Table expand to 2 entity sets?

Tags: sapui5

```
 onBeforeRebind: function(oEvent) 
{
 var mBindingParams =oEvent.getParameter("bindingParams");
 mBindingParams.parameters["expand"] = "Supplier"; 
}
```

How do I expand to 2 entity sets, suppose i have Supplier and Product List Items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a comma between entity sets as follows:

```
 mBindingParams.parameters["expand"] = "Supplier,SecondEntitySet,ThirdEntitySet";
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried this already, not sure but now i dont see any expand calls only in the odata batch call.